# decrypt web.config file for specific project on a local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, web-config

I have a project that is running on the server. I want to modify it on a local machine, but connection strings in the web.config file are encrypted using regiis. To decrypt it I tried this article:
http://ryaremchuk.blogspot.com/2012/11/encrypting-and-decrypting-webconfig.html

I copied the project to a folder on the hard desk on my local machine; so its path is C:\project1.

In the prompt interface I reached: C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. Then I used this command with no luck:

```
aspnet_regiis -pd "connectionStrings" -app "C:\project1"
```

Is my command wrong? Should the project be in a different path?

Comment: are you getting any error or is it just not decrypting ?

Comment: I am getting an error message: the configuration for the virtual path and site  cannot be opened.